# How to achieve rollback in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm quite new to MongoDB so this might be a rookie question.
I've written a script to insert a few records in my database but I want it to be transactional. So that even if an exception arises, all the changes made before this is rollbacked.

```
    try:
    # CONNECTIONS
    db_sql = pymysql.connect(host, user, password, name)
    mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URL, retryWrites=True)
    mongo_db = mongo_client[MONGO_DATABASE_NAME]
    mongo_collection = mongo_db[MONGO_COLLECTION]

    input_list = get_input(db_sql)

    doc_list = get_docs(mongo_collection)

    added_by = "SYSTEM"

    for doc in doc_list:
        for input in input_list:
            bot_ref = input['bot_ref']
            new_doc = {
                'customer_id': doc['customer_id'],
                'channel': doc['channel'],
                'locale': doc['locale'],
                'available_for': bot_ref,
                'display_name': doc['display_name'],
                'added_by': added_by,
                'reply_text': doc['reply_text'],
                'created_on': doc['created_on'],
                'created_by': doc['created_by'],
                'updated_on': doc['updated_on'],
                'updated_by': doc['updated_by']
            }
            mongo_collection.insert_one(new_doc)

except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    raise

finally:
    db_sql.close()
```

get_input() and get_docs() are functions I've written to fetch data from respective DBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoDB version >=4.0(For replicaSets) and >=4.2(For Sharded cluster) multi document transactions are supported , so you can do it following way:

```
with client.start_session() as s:
  def cb(s):
    collection_one.insert_one(doc_one, session=s)
    collection_two.insert_one(doc_two, session=s)
  s.with_transaction(cb)
```

If something happen and operation is not successful during the transaction commit phase , all the changes  will be rolled back automatically  ...